# How to know the input device that was used to open my application?

Tags: android, input-devices, amazon-fire-tv

I need to know how to get the input device that was used to open my application (in the onCreate method, for example) .

A bit more specific, how to know if my app was opened with "Amazon Fire TV Remote Input" or "Amazon Fire Game Controller Input"?.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try dumping out all the fields and extras of the Intent, but if it is not there the information may simply not be available to you.

Comment: You can get useful information from the device configuration: developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html but that will tell you about connected input devices in general, and it may be impossible to answer the exact question you're asking.

Comment: looks like there's nothing there to tell you, until you get a keypress and can then query the ID of the controller. Any reason you need that info at startup?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your answers. I had to change a bit the behavior because I have not found a solution for this. @Offbeatmammal the initial reason was to manipulate the initial behavior of the app, depending on the device that opened. For example, specific guide for a control or another. thanks